# Bootstrap dropdown not workin properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have the following html

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<tr>
<td class="text-center">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div style="background-color:white;width:0.5em;display:inline-block;"></div>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">                                                                      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Vizualizeaza</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adauga</a></li>
        </ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

what i'm trying to do is to make a dropdown, but i have two problems, first one, the div in the middle of the button won't display (i need to make a white delimitation, i don't know if this is the right way i'm trying)

and second, this html it inside a loop and when i click the button, the dropdown opens at the end of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dropdown class for making the dropdown to work as follows

```
<tr>
   <td class="text-center">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div style="background-color:white;width:0.5em;display:inline-block;"></div>
            <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Vizualizeaza</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adauga</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And for making the div visible specify height property as well

```
<div style="background-color:white;width:0.5em;display:inline-block;"></div>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea of what you're trying to accomplish. All of the code to do this can be found on bootstrap's [website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns). That link will direct you to how to create dropdown buttons in bootstrap 3. Additionally, here's a [link](https://www.codeply.com/go/zCX1oNYCZq) to a codeply project with the code in action.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Vizualizeaza</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adauga</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

WORKING EXAMPLE ! Please wrap Button and ul inside a div."'div class="btn-group">'", This should resolve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Basic Table</h2>
      <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true">Button click</i>
            <div style="background-color:white;width:0.5em;display:inline-block;"></div>
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Vizualizeaza</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adauga</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Basically, You should wrap button and ul inside a div with below properties.

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Or you can use bootstrap class "btn-group"